# How to link script to an image google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I add with google script a row in a spreadsheet and then I insert an image in a cell of this row. I want to know if it's possible to link this image to a script's function ?

Comment: You want this to be done with code, or manually?

Answer (score 1):

Insert > image > in top right menu of image, Assign Script.

It's much better practice to create a menu option for a sidebar Add-on to appear that allows users to click actual buttons and not images. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

***How to create an app script:***

1. Go to the option **TOOLS** --> **SCRIPT EDITOR**
2. **FILE** --> **NEW** --> **SCRIPT FILE** --> (Enter the nae of the file (with/without file extension (.gs)))
3. Example file name --> test.gs
4. Create a **function** / Use the existing function and write your app script
5. Example function **onClickImage** { ........ }

***How to add images + assign app script to run from the Spreadsheet:***

6. Go to the option **INSERT** --> **IMAGE**.
7. Choose any of the options to upload the image into the spreadsheet.
8. Click the image and select the option **(:)** available at top-right-corner of the image.
9. Select the **ASSIGN SCRIPT** option
10. Add the created function name **onClickImage** (not the script name test.gs)
11. Now whenever you click the image, the respective assigned app script function will be triggered accordingly.

Comment: If I use the option "Insert image in cell" (which is what I want), then the three dots don't appear when I click or hover over it. Is there anyway to assign the script if it's inserted IN the cell as opposed to OVER the cell? I want to have a linked image in every active cell in a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

In a world where strength and power reign supreme, Goku, the determined Saiyan warrior, embarked on a relentless journey to protect Earth from evil forces. With his unwavering determination and indomitable spirit, Goku trained tirelessly, pushing his limits beyond imagination. Throughout his journey, Goku faced numerous powerful foes and overcame insurmountable odds through sheer willpower and perseverance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).