# Creating down menu with multiple selection capabilties

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a dropdown menu via data validation with a list of items to select from. Traditionally, you're only able to select one item at a time, but I'm curious if there's a way to select more than one item per row. I've attempted to use the below code in the Apps Script -

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if (activeCell.getColumn() == 14 && activeCell.getLastRow && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Accommodations") {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");
    }
    else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
      }
      else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, no matter how many times I save it and refresh the sheet, it doesn't allow me to select multiple options. [Here you can review the spreadsheet I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8yUf.png) [And here you can review all of the different items available in one of the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gveif.png)

Comment: so basically, you want to collect the history of chosen values from the dropdown into a cell?

Comment: @ASyntuBU so using column B for example, I'd like to be able to select MNTN post, PAYG and TikTok all in one row instead of each selection replacing the other

Comment: dropdown is made for single chosen option. i dont think it can be used to choose multiple options.

Comment: the script above is just just accumulating all chosen options into a single value. And I don't think its a good idea as it causes a cell error that is caused by setting a value on a dropdown cell that doesnt belong to the option, unless you can consider it a solution.

Comment: I understand. Any suggestions on a code that I could use to yield the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

If you want to get fancy, here is a way to create a multi select list from dropdown using the checkbox character.  This shows some uses of Named Range, Data Validation, Image Script and an installed onEdit trigger.

I create a Named Range called `Items`.  The first item of `Items` is simply a default `Select Item` that is always displayed.

Next I create a Data Validation in cell B1 that will display the drop down list of `Items`.

Then I create an installed onEdit trigger called `multiSelect` that will toggle the checkbox character.

Finally I create an Over Cell Image button in cell C1 that I can click to display the selected items and attach the script `checkSelect`

[image]

**Script**

```
function multiSelect(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "MultiSelect" ) {  // only if on sheet MultiSelect
      if( e.range.getA1Notation() === "B1" ) {  // only if in cell B1
        if( e.value === "Select Item" ) return;
        let ranges = e.range.getSheet().getNamedRanges();
        let items = ranges.find( range => range.getName() === "Items" );
        if( items ) {
          let values = items.getRange().getValues();
          let index = values.findIndex( item => item[0].slice(1) === e.value.slice(1) );
          let item = values[index][0];
          if( item.charAt(0) === '☐' ) {
            item = item.replace('☐','☒');
          }
          else {
            item = item.replace('☒','☐');
          }
          items.getRange().getCell(index+1,1).setValue(item);
          e.range.setValue("Select Item");
        }
        else {
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Oops what happend to Items");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in multiSelect - "+err);
  }
}

function checkSelect() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let ranges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
    let items = ranges.find( range => range.getName() === "Items" );
    if( items ) {
      let values = items.getRange().getValues();
      let picks = "";
      values.forEach( item => { if( item[0].charAt(0) === '☒') picks = picks.concat(item[0].slice(1),',') } );
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" You picked "+picks);
    }
    else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Oops what happend to Items");
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in checkSelect - "+err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904695/how-to-link-script-to-an-image-google-script#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20option%20INSERT,Select%20the%20ASSIGN%20SCRIPT%20option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904695/how-to-link-script-to-an-image-google-script#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20option%20INSERT,Select%20the%20ASSIGN%20SCRIPT%20option)